# Meaning of document in chrome extension InjectDetails

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, document

I am using `InjectDetails` object in my chrome extension code. I am little confused about the document referred in `runAt` field.

Here is snippet from [documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#type-InjectDetails)

```
runAt ( optional enum of "document_start", "document_end", or "document_idle" )
```

Which document is referred here ? Possible options are:-

- Original document (Parent frame which is loaded in browser).
- Document in which JS/Css are going to be injected. (There may be multiple iframes inside original document)
- Document running in background as background.html

How should I verify this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `allFrames` is `true`, then "document"  only refers to the top-level document.
Otherwise, it refers to the document of each matched frame (e.g. top-level, iframe).

You can find more information about `run_at` at the [Content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) documentation:

> ```
> run_at    string
> ```
>
> *Optional.* Controls when the files in `js` are injected. Can be "document_start", "document_end", or "document_idle". Defaults to "document_idle".
>
> In the case of "document_start", the files are injected after any files from `css`, but before any other DOM is constructed or any other script is run.
>
> In the case of "document_end", the files are injected immediately after the DOM is complete, but before subresources like images and frames have loaded.
>
> In the case of "document_idle", the browser chooses a time to inject scripts between "document_end" and immediately after the [`window.onload`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#handler-onload) event fires. The exact moment of injection depends on how complex the document is and how long it is taking to load, and is optimized for page load speed.
>
> **Note**: With "document_idle", content scripts may not necessarily receive the `window.onload` event, because they may run after it has already fired. In most cases, listening for the `onload` event is unnecessary for content scripts running at "document_idle" because they are guaranteed to run after the DOM is complete. If your script definitely needs to run after `window.onload`, you can check if onload has already fired by using the [`document.readyState`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#dom-document-readystate) property.

PS. The property names are camelCased for [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript) (`runAt`, `allFrames`), but spelled with an underscore in the manifest file (`run_at`, `all_frames`).